# Bootstrap - change h1 color to text-primary

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out the way how can I change font color of h1 to pre-defined class text-primary. Is there any way that I can assign text-primary to h1 class?

something similar to this:

```
h1 {font-size: 28px !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: text-primary;
}
```

Comment: `color:initial;` ?? I have never heard about a color called `text-primary`

Comment: What is `text-primary`? Is it a variable set with any CSS preprocessor?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162366/with-twitter-bootstrap-how-can-i-customize-the-h1-text-color-of-one-page-and-le

Answer (score 3):

just add that class to h1

```
<h1 class="text-primary">your title</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is text-primary a class? If yes:

```
.text-primary, h1 {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to `class` attribute inside `h1` tag as in below way :

```
<h1 class="text-primary">Some heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you use LESS and Bootstrap's LESS sources or not.

You have to search for the definition of the style of class `text-primary` in Bootstrap's sources. If you use LESS, you will want to look in the LESS sources, otherwise in the resulting complied CSS sources of the Bootstrap frame work.

In LESS in v3.3.4 the style is:

```
.text-primary {
    .text-emphasis-variant(@brand-primary);
}
```

Copy that style into your h1 style and compile again:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 28px !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    .text-emphasis-variant(@brand-primary);
}
```

The *mixin* `text-emphasis-variant` creates several style rules. You do not have to take care about it because LESS does it for you.

If you work with CSS directly, you simply search for the style definition of `text-primary` in the CSS and copy all styles to your h1 style definition.